# Aeroplane mode turning on after sleep/suspend mode

Tags: networking, internet, suspend, 17.04

My HP Notebook activates Aeroplane mode after resuming from suspend/sleep. The Aeroplane mode is not able to turn off by using hardware or software switch.

Every time laptop goes to suspend/sleep, I have to reboot to connect to the internet. Not only Ubuntu, even Fedora has same problem.

Any solution to this?

Edit :

Laptop - HP Pavilion Notebook - 15-ab032tx

processor - Intel® Core™ i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz × 4

Graphics - Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) / Gallium 0.4 on NV118

Comment: Suggestion: Include details of the laptop specifications i.e. model, cpu, graphic card. The issue might be related to your hardware support.

Comment: Yes the issue is regarding hardware because my friend having hp notebook (not same model) has same issue.

Comment: Read `man pm-action` - it will lead you to the scripts that are executed when your system does a Freeze/Thaw/Suspend/Resume. One of these scripts MAY cause your trouble.